# Kotlin & Spring MVC - HTTP Status 400 - Null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have a Kotlin `@RestController`, and I would expect it to return `400` *Bad Request* in a situation where a `null` is passed for a `@RequestParam` argument.

**Example:**

```
@RestController
class Api() {

  @PostMapping("endpoint")
  fun endpoint(@DateTimeFormat(iso = DATE) @RequestParam date: LocalDate) {
    //do something
  }
}
```

If I were to make a request to POST `/endpoint?date` I get a `500` *Internal Server Error* with the following (shortened) body:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2020-09-14T20:39:38.102+0000",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "Parameter specified as non-null is null: method Api.endpoint, parameter date",
  "trace": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method Api.endpoint, parameter date\r\n\tat Api.endpoint(Api.kt)\r\n\t 
    ...
    ...
    atjava.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)\r\n",
 "path": "/campaigns/contributions/unfunded/retries"
}
```

Is there any way to fix this using either some additional library, a configuration, or some custom code that does not have other side effects that keeps everything the same except that the status code will be `400` *Bad Request*

Answer (score 1):

The following works for Kotlin 1.4.*. This is not necessarily the best answer because there is no guarantee that Kotlin will not change the excption type of message in future releases. For eaxample, when I originally asked the question I was using 1.3.*, and the exception was `IllegalArgumentException`. In 1.4.* it has been changed to NullPointerException.

```
@ControllerAdvice
class KotlinNonNullParamHandling {

    @ExceptionHandler
    protected fun handleKotlinNonNullViolation(
        exception: NullPointerException,
        response: HttpServletResponse
    ) {
        val nullParameter = exception.message?.startsWith("Parameter specified as non-null is null: ") == true
        val restController = exception
            .stackTrace
            .getOrNull(0)
            ?.let { Class.forName(it.className) }
            ?.getAnnotation(RestController::class.java) != null
        val status =
            if (nullParameter && restController) HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST
            else HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
        response.sendError(status.value(), exception.message)
    }
}
```

Before assuming that it is 400, we are checking that the exception

- is a `NullPointerException`
- has a message starting with "Parameter specified as non-null is null: "
- it was thrown from a class the is RestController (otherwise it might be some other problem, such as a null being sent to a method by reflection having nothing to do with the web layer.)

Answer (score 0):

Spring will throw the IllegalArgumentException by default when a validation fails here. Every exception inside your Spring-Boot application will be treated by default as InternalServerError.
You can modify your response code by adding a function like this:

```kotlin
@RestController
class Api() {

  @ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException.class)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
  public void onIllegalArgumentException(IllegalArgumentException e) {
  }

  @PostMapping("endpoint")
  fun endpoint(@DateTimeFormat(iso = DATE) @RequestParam date: LocalDate) {
    //do something
  }
}
```

Afterwards you'll get the 400 status code on invalid request param.

Answer (score -1):

I've tested your code, and there's nothing obviously wrong with it - works as expected.

```
curl -v -d "date=2020-10-01" http://localhost:8080/endpoint
*   Trying ::1:8080...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /endpoint HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 15
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 15 out of 15 bytes
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Tue, 13 Oct 2020 07:04:21 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

So I would:

1. Verify that the client is properly formatting the request - e.g. try explicitly setting the Content-Type header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, check if there's no typo in the param name etc.
2. That you have Jackson properly configured to work with Kotlin (com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin - dependency)

Comment: My question is looking at a case where the date is null, which causes Kotlin to throw an exception. This leads to a 500 error, but 400 would be more appropriate in this case.

Comment: Oh, I've missread your question, sorry about that. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @joseph-k-strauss, have you tried StefanD answer?

Comment: That answer will return 400, even for legitimate 500 errors, i.e., there are other reasons for an IllegalArgumentException to be thrown.